# Can Erlang R16B02 be built on OSX 10.10.5 with OpenSSL?

Tags: macos, openssl, erlang, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I need to build Erlang R16B02 on OSX 10.10.5 with support for SSL so I can use `crypto` application. I have already installed OpenSSL 0.9.8 with Homebrew. Running `openssl` `> version` yields the following:

```
$ openssl
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
```

I am able to get Erlang R16B02 built and installed, but I consistently get the same error when trying to start the `crypto` application:

```
1> crypto:start().
** exception error: undefined function crypto:start/0
2>
=ERROR REPORT==== 1-Feb-2016::14:19:17 ===
Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:
"load_failed, Failed to load NIF library: 'dlopen(~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.1/priv/lib/crypto.so, 2): Symbol not found: _AES_cbc_encrypt
  Referenced from: ~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.1/priv/lib/crypto.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.1/priv/lib/crypto.so'"
OpenSSL might not be installed on this system.

=ERROR REPORT==== 1-Feb-2016::14:19:17 ===
The on_load function for module crypto returned {error,
                                                 {load_failed,
                                                  "Failed to load NIF library: 'dlopen(~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.1/priv/lib/crypto.so, 2): Symbol not found: _AES_cbc_encrypt\n  Referenced from: ~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.1/priv/lib/crypto.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in ~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.1/priv/lib/crypto.so'"}}
```

I have tried calling other functions, like `crypto:module_info()`, but I always get the same error. I have built Erlang R16B02 with various flags using [asdf](https://github.com/HashNuke/asdf). Here a couple combinations I tried:

```
Building with options: --enable-dynamic-ssl-lib --prefix=~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02

Building with options: --with-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl --prefix=~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02 # with-ssl points to the OpenSSL install

Building with options: --with-ssl --prefix=~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02
```

All of these resulted in the same error. One strange thing I noticed when I was trying to figure out how to get Erlang built with SSL was the `--enable-darwin-64bit` and the `--enable-darwin-universal` flags caused the build to fail. This seems odd as I am building on OSX, so it seems like these flags would be required.

So to recap:

- I am using [asdf](https://github.com/HashNuke/asdf) (shouldn't really matter though)
- With all the successfully builds I get the error above when invoking any function in the `crypto` module
- I have Erlang 17 built with OpenSSL and the `crypto` application

**Update**

I came across this https://gist.github.com/ThePicard/7378417 so I tried a couple of the options listed there for the configure script but I still got the same error.

**Update 2**

`otool -L ~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.1/priv/lib/crypto.so` prints this:

```
~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.1/priv/lib/crypto.so:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

Comment: What does `otool -L ~/.asdf/installs/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.1/priv/lib/crypto.so` show? What happens if you set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in your shell to `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` and export it before running `erl` and `crypto:start()`?

Comment: Updated the question with the output of otool. Setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not change the output of the `crypto` module function calls in the `erl` session.

Comment: The `otool` command should be showing that your `crypto.so` NIF has a dependency on `libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib`. I just now built R16B02 successfully with standard openssl on 10.10.5, and that `libcrypto` dependency is present for `crypto.so`. Does your output from `configure` show that it's finding `libcrypto` successfully?

Comment: The only thing I see is `checking for static ZLib to be used by SSL in standard locations... no
checking for OpenSSL kerberos 5 support... no`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using openssl that comes with OS X, given that on 10.10.5 `/usr/bin/openssl` shows exactly the same version as yours? If I were you I'd start a whole new fresh build area and try again.

Comment: Good idea. I uninstalled the brew OpenSSL and just used the OpenSSL that came preinstalled with OSX. That didn't change the error. I finally tried this configure call that got it working: `CFLAGS="-DOPENSSL_NO_EC=1"  ./configure --enable-dynamic-ssl-lib --without-wx --prefix=/somewhere/`. I don't fully understand why this works when the others  but once I do I'll post an answer with links to the relevant messages in the mailing list once I understand what's going on.

Comment: Actually, while that configure call with `--enable-dynamic-ssl-lib` did succeed, this works as well: `./configure --without-wx --prefix=/somewhere/`. If I leave out the `--without-wx` it fails, but being that I don't have wxWidgets installed that makes sense. Thanks for your help Steve!